# Finding the Index of an Element in a Vector using R

Tags: vector

I'm working with R and I have a vector, let's call it "my_vector", containing various elements. I need to find the index of a specific element within this vector. Is there a built-in function or a recommended approach for accomplishing this in R?

For example, if I have a vector c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50) and I want to find the index of the element 30, how can I achieve this in an efficient way